# Catch some exceptions and throw only a new one with the info of all the previous

Tags: java, exception

I have a for loop with a try/catch block inside. If any exception is thrown I store them in a list and allow the loop to continue procesing.

When the loop has finished I pretend to throw an exception that encapsulates all the info (messages and stack traces) of all the stored exceptions.

I have thought on concatenating messages and stack traces and creating a new Exception with this info but I guess if there is a better approach.

```
List<Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
for (.....) {
    try{
        someProcessThatMayThrowAnException();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        exceptions.add(ex);
    }
}

if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(exceptions)) {
    StringBuilder messages = new StringBuilder();
    for (Exception ex : exceptions) {
        messages.append(ex.getMessage()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        for (StackTraceElement ste : ex.getStackTrace()) {
            messages.append(ste.toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }

    throw new RuntimeException(messages.toString());
}
```

Comment: How about adding all those exceptions as suppressed ones by using [Throwable#addSuppressed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed-java.lang.Throwable-)

Comment: You may want to use a ChainedException pattern.  Google it.  It allows you to chain the exceptions together, collecting all of the pervious exceptions to the last.  (If I'm understanding the problem correctly)

Comment: addSuppresed seems to me like the correct approach. ChainedException seems more appropiate for nested exceptions than for siblings exceptions like is my case.